# Attached Plugin Registration process to Visual Studio skips breakpoints on static async Task<T> methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm using the guide on how to [Debug CRM Online Plugins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ife_rHq-wSo&t=165s) using the Plugin Registration tool by attaching the process to Visual Studio.

The function `MakeRequest` I want to step into is below.

```
tracingService.Trace("Calling API. . .");
var x = await MyProject.Services.HttpRequestService.MakeRequest("POST", string.Format(Constants.ENDPOINT, idForEndpointUrl), body).Result;
tracingService.Trace(x);
```

But the `MakeRequest` method is always skipped when stepping through my code at this point. Interestingly, when I put a watch on `x` it's value is given as error even though it is in the same scope. The error for `x` is `error CS0103: The name x does not exist in the current context`.

I'm also getting this error when using ILMerge to take care of my Newtonsoft dependency.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Download the details and load with Plug-in Profiler.
|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|Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ActivityId>c3760db5-7ebc-4327-82ab-e0feebefd4ba</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147220891</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>OperationStatus</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">3</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>SubErrorCode</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">-2146233088</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>Download the details and load with Plug-in Profiler.
|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|</Message>
  <Timestamp>2017-11-30T20:00:53.9540235Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[PluginProfiler.Plugins: PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerPlugin]
[419e2f1c-09d6-e711-a951-000d3a108ae0: DYN.SpurGo.Gamification.EventTrigger: Create of account (Profiler)]

A trace log
Another trace log
Calling API
I wonder what Success looks like :/?
```

Comment: You‘re sure that your source is the same version as the assembly?

Comment: That is possible :/. I was hoping I'd be able to work around it since I'm taking a dependency on Newtonsoft and was able to use ILMerge to update my .dll along with it. But when I start execution based on the error log from deploying that version of the plugin, I can't step through my code at all.

Comment: I'd like to share those error details here, but will need to remove any private org information from it first.